# Hiding a UIView & Updating Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, autolayout, constraints

I have a custom table view cell nib that takes in two textView's, two imageViews, and 4 labels. The constraints are set using autolayout and this is how the nib looks:

[image]

The main image view on the right takes in an optional value from the database. If the user has included an image, I want it to show the image, but if the user hasn't, I want the image to be hidden and I want the constraints for the textView (custom description to its left) to be adjusted and look like this:

[image]

I'm sure this is fairly simple to do, but I'm still learning, so what I'm asking for is to be pointed in the right direction. What is the best way to go about switching the constraints based off of the values that are stored?

Answer (score 3):

You could set your constraints so that there is a horizontal spacing constant between the body text and the image view, and another between the image view the the edge of its superview.

From there, you could create a width constraint for the image view and set the `constant` of its `IBOutlet` to `0`.

Comment: So basically, if the image isn't there, I would set the width of the image view to 0?

Comment: Wow thats genius. Thank you for the idea

Answer (score 1):

I think this is most easily done with `UIStackView`s.

For the many labels on the left, put them in a vertical stack view or just a regular `UIView`. Then put their parent view in a horizontal stack view, together with the image. The horizontal stack view should fill proportionally.

When you configure your table view cell, add/remove the image view as appropriate. Here's some pseudocode:

```
if data[indexPath.row].image != nil
    if imageView.parent == nil 
        horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
    imageView.image = data.image
else if imageView.parent != nil
    imageView.removeFromSuperview()
```